# SQL - Response time count range for specific Name field

Tags: sql

Need help on below query . I have table where it stores Name & its response time .I need to create a report where each name should seggrate in below format for an week.Looking for range counts(response time), total volume & avg(response time)

```
NAME    0TO5    5TO10   10TO60  60TO120 120+    TOTAL   AVG(rt)
A           
B                           
C                           
D
```

FOR EXAMPLE - COUNT 2 ON (0TO5),COUNT 9 ON (5TO10),COUNT 15 ON (10TO60),COUNT 11 ON (60TO120),COUNT 34 ON (120+), tOTAL OF COUNT(71) & AVG(rt)

Comment: You should include sample input table data as well.  My guess is that you just need a basic pivot query here.  Also, which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is:

```
create table my_table (
  name varchar(10),
  rt int
);
```

Your query should look like:

```
select 
    name,
    sum(case when rt <= 5 then 1 end) as '0to5',
    sum(case when rt > 5 and rt <= 10 then 1 end) as '5to10',
    sum(case when rt > 10 and rt <= 60 then 1 end) as '10to60',
    sum(case when rt > 60 and rt <= 120 then 1 end) as '60to120',
    sum(case when rt > 120 then 1 end) as '120+',
    count(*) as 'total',
    avg(rt) as avg
  from my_table
  group by name
```